# How does the final self joined table remember the association?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm learning SQL and have come across a problem that needs a self-join. I've been playing around with the query to understand why the self-join table lays it out the way it does, but haven't had much luck

```
Create table Departments (DepartmentID int primary key, Name text);

insert into Departments values
(1001,'SRO'),
(2001,'Drs'),
(3001,'Accounting');

Create table Employees 
(
  EmployeeID int not null, 
  DepartmentID int not null,
  ManagerID int,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Salary int not null,
  primary key(EmployeeID),
  foreign key (DepartmentID)
    references Departments(DepartmentID)
 );

insert into Employees values
(68319,1001,NULL,'Kayling','6000.00'),
(66928,3001,68319,'Blaze','2750.00'),
(67832,1001,68319,'Clare','2550.00'),
(65646,2001,68319,'Jonas','2957.00'),
(67858,2001,65646,'Scarlet','3100.00'),
(69062,2001,65646,'Frank','3100.00'),
(63679,2001,69062,'Sandrine','900.00'),
(64989,3001,66928,'Adelyn','1700.00'),
(65271,3001,66928,'Wade','1350.00');
```

Now perform two queries to understand what the table was like originally and what it became after the self-join

Query 1

```
select * from Employees order by Employeeid;
```

Query 2

```
select * from Employees e1 
join Employees e2 on
e2.ManagerID = e1.EmployeeID
order by e1.employeeid;
```

The results I get are:

Query 1

```
EmployeeID  DepartmentID    ManagerID   Name        Salary
63679       2001            69062       Sandrine    900
64989       3001            66928       Adelyn      1700
65271       3001            66928       Wade        1350
65646       2001            68319       Jonas       2957
66928       3001            68319       Blaze       2750
67832       1001            68319       Clare       2550
67858       2001            65646       Scarlet     3100
68319       1001            null        Kayling     6000
69062       2001            65646       Frank       3100
```

Query 2 Results

```
EmployeeID  DepartmentID    ManagerID   Name    Salary  EmployeeID  DepartmentID    ManagerID   Name        Salary
65646       2001            68319       Jonas   2957    69062       2001            65646       Frank       3100
65646       2001            68319       Jonas   2957    67858       2001            65646       Scarlet     3100
66928       3001            68319       Blaze   2750    65271       3001            66928       Wade        1350
66928       3001            68319       Blaze   2750    64989       3001            66928       Adelyn      1700
68319       1001            null        Kayling 6000    67832       1001            68319       Clare       2550
68319       1001            null        Kayling 6000    66928       3001            68319       Blaze       2750
68319       1001            null        Kayling 6000    65646       2001            68319       Jonas       2957
69062       2001            65646       Frank   3100    63679       2001            69062       Sandrine    900
```

Now my understanding of query two is on the first column only show the managerID and not anyone else (e.g staff only).

This type of self join should allow me to find all the employees (staff) who are managed by each manager. How does a new join table remember that the first salary column relates to the manager while last relates to the employee. Is there no intelligence in the table but rather in the query e.g. e1 and e1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query list managers first and their related employees, you need to inverse the condition :

```
select e1.*, e2.*
from Employees e1 
left join Employees e2 on e1.ManagerID = e2.EmployeeID
order by e1.employeeid;
```

`left join` can be used to also list employees without managers.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/b2kn-XMH)

Comment: Drat... I missed this, and fixed it inadvertently xD

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` (as opposed to using `e1.*` or individual column names as in `e1.EmployeeID`) just displays all columns one after the other. Your table has 5 columns, so you get all 5 from `FROM` followed by all 5 from from `JOIN`.

You can always be more explicit:

```
select
    emp.EmployeeID, man.Salary as EmployeeSalary,
    man.EmployeeID as ManagerEmployeeId, man.Salary as ManagerSalary
from Employees emp
inner join Employees man on employee.ManagerID = man.EmployeeID
order by em.employeeid;
```

Using meaningful aliases also helps to detect errors like the reversed condition your original query has.